# how to get json from github

Tags: json, github

I can't get **Repl.it** to pull json from github. Do I need the api
or just a better url?

Errors:

1. While using the url **https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Xiija/FakeDB/master/db.json**

> TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

2. While using this url **Xiija.github.io/JSON/db.json**

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.

But, when I add https to it **https://Xiija.github.io/JSON/db.json**

> TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

**The request**

```
    const myHeaders = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',  // text/xml  .. application/json
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
        'accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3.raw',
        'user-agent': 'dataApi'
    });
    
  
    let tm = new Date().getTime();
    const myRequest = new Request(url + '?time=' + tm, {
      method: 'GET',
      rejectUnauthorized: false, 
      insecureHTTPParser: true,
      mode: 'cors',
      cache: 'default',
      headers: myHeaders,   
    });
```

Comment: Testing on codepen... both of these urls return json when pasted into a browser
"https://Xiija.github.io/JSON/db.json"
"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
but only the jsonplaceholder one returns data in codepen

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

GitHub does not allow CORS pre-flight requests (`OPTIONS` requests) on GitHub Pages content (the `xiija.github.io` URL) or raw content (the `raw.githubusercontent.com` URL), so the browser decides that you are not permitted to access these URLs.

What you need is to avoid sending the pre-flight request. Your `myHeaders` code is the problem here: setting the `Content-Type: application/json` and Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` is causing the pre-flight request.

For several reasons, you should not be sending any of the headers you are sending:

- `Content-Type` header on a `Request` is only for requests that have a body (e.g. `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`), not for `GET` requests.
- `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header is for responses, not requests.
- `Accept` header is only helpful if the server cares about it, but GitHub Pages and raw file access don't use it.
- `User-Agent` is ignored by the browser and the browser's built-in user agent is sent instead.

Here is a version of your code that works:

```js
const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Xiija/FakeDB/master/db.json';

let tm = new Date().getTime();
const myRequest = new Request(url + '?time=' + tm, {
  method: 'GET',
  rejectUnauthorized: false, 
  insecureHTTPParser: true,
  mode: 'cors',
  cache: 'default',
});

fetch(myRequest).then(r => r.json()).then(r => console.log(r))
```